# Using String.Format to specify the decimal places at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, precision, numeric, string.format

I want to use String.Format to specify the number of decimal places to display where the number of decimal places may change at runtime.

Normally I would do this:

```
Dim d As Decimal = 1.23456D
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("My number to 2 decimal places is {0:f2}", d))
```

What I want to do is this:

```
Dim d As Decimal = 1.23456D
Dim places as integer = 2
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("My number to {0} decimal places is {1:f" + places.ToString + "}", places, d))
```

But without having to concat the string. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. The best I can think would be to nest your `string.Format` calls, which would be awful. I'd be tempted to pull the formatting out into what you pass the format, though: `string.Format("...places is {1}", places, d.ToString("f" + places));`. They're each kind of icky, I know, but at least then you're dealing with a constant format string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without concatenating the string you can do it like this

```
 Dim d As Decimal = 1.23456D
 Dim places As Integer = 2
 Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("My number to {0} decimal places is {1}", places, Decimal.Round(d, places)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension to format the value to string with the number of places desired.  It hides the details of the implementation in a function but makes it as easy to use as `ToString`:

```vb
<Extension()>
Public Function ToStringPlaces(value As Decimal, places As Integer) As String
    ' ToDo: error checking
    Return String.Format(value.ToString("f" & places.ToString))
End Function
```

Test:

```
Private pi As Decimal = 22/7
'...
Label1.Text = pi.ToStringPlaces(3)

==> 3.142
```